# Mysql or other?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'd like to create a system which would output keywords and positions for which a domain appears in SE search results. Assuming that gathering the data is not a problem, which DBMS should I choose?

I've tried regular MySQL design for many-to-many relation:

```
domain:id,name 
keyword:id,phrase 
domain_keyword:domain_id,keyword_id,rank
```

but it results in an index of a huge size for the domain_keyword table.
I wonder if perhaps the problem has a better solution using DBMS other than MySQL?

Comment: Switching dbms systems isn't going to reduce key sizes. Lots of data = big indexes, regardless of whichever system you settle on. Beyond that, this question is asking for opinion, not concrete facts, so it'll be closed.

Comment: @MarcB slightly disagree. Yea it looks like an opinion question, if you know the answer, but learning that some problem is an inherent design problem and not a question of DBMS seems legit to me.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is a basic database design issue and different DMBS handle this very similarly. Ask yourself a different question: Which feature would you hope for that might exist in another DBMS?

Comment: you might use a different database design though. for example, do you need each single hit? (I assume rank means order in the query?) Or can't you just count the occurrences of each term?

Comment: What I want is to output that a domain appears on X position for "keyword 1", on Y position for "keyword 2" and so on. For the first question, I hope that maybe some non-relation dbms suits better for my needs. I don't know much about them.

Comment: Ok I misunderstood the purpose of your DBs. If you never (or rarely) want to ask "show me all the keywords and ranks for this domain" but only "show me all the domains and ranks for this keyword" and you're really short on space, you could drop the index on domain_id.

Answer (score 0):

All relational databases have similar characteristics. There's no silver bullet in here. You should focus on your schema design.